# Cannot resolve for method show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I've on API 23.Using `RadialTimePickerDialogFragment` that uses v4 
The parent activity is based on Activity (we don't need

Why am I getting

> Cannot resolve for method show(android.app.FragmentManager,
>   java.lang.String)

```
import com.codetroopers.betterpickers.radialtimepicker.RadialTimePickerDialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import com.gtfp.workingmemory.BuildConfig;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.R;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.colorPicker.colorPickerActivity;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.colorPicker.colorPickerView;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.frmwrk.frmwrkActivity;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.settings.SettingsActivity;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.settings.appSettings;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.todo.ToDoAlarm;
import com.gtfp.workingmemory.todo.ToDoItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
    :
    :
    :
    :
     RadialTimePickerDialogFragment rtpd = new RadialTimePickerDialogFragment()
                            .setOnTimeSetListener(editToDoItem.this)
                            .setStartTime(10, 10)
                            .setThemeDark();

                    rtpd.show(getFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_TIME_PICKER);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:
The show method in `RadialTimePickerDialogFragment` required the v4 FragmentManager (ie. getSupportFragmentManager). Obviously, RadialTimePickerDialogFragment is an old class.

This means changing the parent Activity from extending Activity to extending `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and using `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

```
public class editToDoItem extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
:
:
:
RadialTimePickerDialogFragment rtpd = new RadialTimePickerDialogFragment()
                .setOnTimeSetListener(editToDoItem.this)
                .setStartTime(mTP.getCurrentHour(),mTP.getCurrentMinute());

rtpd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_TIME_PICKER);
```